# elasticsearch & kibana: sort and/or filter on "_version"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an index that is continuously updated with docs (see node.js code snippet below).... so I'm using the update API with `doc_as_upsert: true`.
I DO get the version number back in the update response.

I just can't seem to show/query the `_version` number in kibana (3.0). Is that just not possible or am I overlooking an "hidden" feature here. I would like to to be able to query for new additions (`_version == 1`)

When using Sense to query I have to explicitly add the "version": true parameter to _search to get the version numbers added to the response array. Do I need to "modify" kibana to accomplish this?

```
esclient.update({
        index: movie.index,
        type: "movie",
        id: movie.url,
        body: {
            "doc": movie,
            "doc_as_upsert": true
        }
    }).then(function(resp) {
        if (resp._version == 1) {
            var prefix = "";
            if (movie.HD) prefix = "HD -> "
            logger.info("new movie", prefix + movie.title);
        }
    }, function(err) {
        console.log("insertElasticsearch", err.message);
    });
```

Comment: What is it exactly your question? Why do you can not see the `_version` field in Kibana? If so, maybe it is related with this issue: https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/issues/542. It seems that you can not see some internal fields from ElasticSearch in Kibana.

Comment: That is my question indeed. I can't "see" or "use" the _version field, I want to and I don't know how-to :-)